# MS Visio Control System stencils

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

I'm new to MS Visio and I was wondering where can I find some stencil to sketch a control system like this:

[image]

I know that this can be obtained with Tikz, but I'd like something easier to use.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any special stencil for those shapes. Just use the standard rectangle and circle shapes from the ribbon. The standard connector should do just what you want as well. For the extra text boxes just add a standard text box.

Comment: http://www.paulherber.co.uk/articles/visio-articles/control-systems/